# Repeat Problem of tableview cell during scrolling in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

There are 5 cells and each cell has one dynamic label. the height of cell is defined as per label content using heightForRowAtIndexPath method. Now, 3 cells are being displayed. When I scroll for next cells then cellForRowAtIndexPath is called once and In the output any one (4 OR 5) cell is displayed correctly but another has 1st cell content(repeating).
Is there any solution to fix this? cellForRowAtIndexPath method should be called 2 times.
I have defined sections and rows correctly.

Comment: You probably are not reusing the cells correctly.  Please provide a sample of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code.

Comment: Hi Brij, The best thing to do in this case is use the concept of reuse as it is defined. You can reuse, all the time you need a cellView that match with the one needed. In the answer that you put as correct, you will never do this. On my answer I give an approach that can be used to avoid create one new cellView for each row, but to create an identifier for each kind of cellView. Ok, in the worst case it would create one cellView for each row, but on the average you will have a better performance than only create new views everytime.

Comment: The same table view is being used multiple times with different data on different button click. The data is different. I am using tableview as a template that's why I need to recreate cell each time.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the judgement

if (cell == nil)

That's good.I solve my problem now.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are not reusing the cells correctly. When you scroll, a previous cell is reused by the `UITableView`, but you don't change its contents correctly.

The code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should look similar to this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"CustomCellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    return cell;
}
```

Does your look like this?

Comment: Yes, I am adding label as per indexPath using switch statement.

Comment: Could you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have a fixed size for each row, you won't be able to reuse them, except to present the same content again or some similar content.

My suggestion is to create a identifier for each row with different size.

You said that you have a switch to add the content based on the indexPath, so you should dequeue the reusable cells inside each case statement, based on its size.

Answer (score 0):

Never remove `if(cell == nil)`.

Instead clear the subviews which you have added on cell.

```
  if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
       }else{
       NSArray *cellSubviews= [cell.contentView cellSubviews];
        for (UIView * view in subviews) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";

    }
    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and give a unique identifier for every cell,

**NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:"Cell %d",indexpath.row];**

don't know if this is the right way, but it should solve ur problem.

Answer (score -6):

The problem is that the cell is not nill so it returns same cell multiple times while scrolling. I removed the condition from cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
if (cell == nil)
```

Now each time, It is allocating cell and works fine.

Comment: Please bear in mind that (performance-wise) this is **the worst you could have done**.

Comment: The same table view is being used multiple times with different data on different button click. Let me know what should be done in this case instead of calling viewcontroller multiple times.