# Values are getting cleared from UITableViewCell while scrolling

Tags: iphone

I have placed three buttons over UITableViewCell and its background is set to an unselect radio button image.

While clicking the button I'm again setting the background image as select button.

In a row one select button should persist but while scrolling UITableView all the selected button images are getting cleared

Can somebody please give me any idea how to do this in this way or in other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are not reusing the cells correctly. When you scroll, a previous cell is reused by the `UITableView`, but you don't change its contents correctly. Here is a sample code for ur reference

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [urDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: While not word-for-word, it looks like you lifted this answer from Adam's original here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027455/repeat-problem-of-tableview-cell-during-scrolling-in-iphone/2027478#2027478 .  If so, you should give him proper credit.

Answer (score 0):

save the state of you button in table datasource.
set that value to your button. table is reloading each displayed row while scrolling.